# 404 when trying to upload different file types

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, forms

I have a form and a controller. On form submit, the controller method is called, and being hit.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult PostDocument(
    IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files, 
    IEnumerable<string> classifications, 
    string loanAppId, 
    string loanNumber)
{
    List<UploadedDocument> uploadedDocuments = new List<UploadedDocument>();
...
```

When I select .txt files in my form to upload, the method gets called, and happiness ensues. When I try to upload a .pdf, I get a 404 error.

Any thoughts why I might be getting a 404 error when I upload different file types? Is there some config setting somewhere preventing this? If so, why would a 404 error be the result?

Comment: Probably it is not the file _type_ but the file _size_. Try uploading a large TXT file and a small PDF file to proof.

Comment: @UweKeim yes, it was the file size. An incorrect setting in the web.config had been set: `<requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1024" />`. Thank you for the tip!

Comment: Glad you were able to resolve it. Be aware that the web.config was providing a local override although you can still run into the limitation from the IIS configuration side of things. By default I believe the max size is 4 MB. This is configured via the "MaxRequestLength" property.

Comment: @WarrenRox You're right, we had to change that as well. Thanks! Also, this project will live in Azure - do you know what the limitations are there?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using IIS you should ensure that the file extension PDF (and any others that you wish to allow) have been configured. Out of the box certain file types will be blocked.

Check at the site level and individual subweb (for any override) under "Request Filtering->File Name Extensions" tab in IIS 7.5.

Comment: Never heard of an _upload_ filter for file types. Can you give a reference?

Comment: Probably you mean [this](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/requestfiltering). Although it supports the `POST` verb, I cannot see how it would deep-inspect the uploaded data. I guess it only inspects the URL being posted to.

Comment: Only 404, but the issue had to do with file size limits in the web.config.